# Triangular Shaped Text

Tags: tables, shapepar

I need something like this [this](http://danicachancdf.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/screenshot_03.jpg):
Searching around I've found only material about tables, rotated text, diagonal lines and so on. I think the solution could be something like drawing a table with no borders, only one cell, with an (invisible) diagonal line crossing it, but I'm not sure and moreover I haven't any idea about implementing it. Help would be appreciated, I'm going mad. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Basically my question would be: how can a column of text that varies in width be implemented? The idea would be having something similar to a journal article, written on two columns, with this columns varying in width during the article, keeping the distance between them fixed, preserving a good text appearance (not too many blank spaces between words and so on). I red about shapepar, but it only arranges text in a particular shape, that remains an "isolated" object in the page. On the other hand I want someting that is "continous", a real textual layout that can be used for entire paragraphs.

Comment: This link is very useful, but it doesn't answer completely my question: There the text ends at the end of the first column and continues on the second. Moreover, there is always a break between what is above the box and the box itself (the same is true for what is below, obviously). What I mean is: is there a way to define a command like "\dtext{type here}" to obtain [something similar](http://imageshack.us/f/443/rk8f.jpg), where the part marked continues indefinitely until needed, depending on the lenght of the text? Also, is it possible deciding if you want it on the left or on the right?

Comment: ...shapepar seems difficult to use for automatised processes, when you don't know how many lines you will need before you type! Maybe defining what I want with shapepar is possible, but it would be a pain. Is there an easier method to do this?